# Titlesec and Arabxetex

Tags: xetex, titlesec, arabxetex

Is there a conflict between `arabxetex` and `titlesec`? In the MWE below, it seems that `titlesec` is ignored (though it does not give any error or warning).

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}


\usepackage{titlesec}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\bfseries\Large}
{\filleft\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} \Huge\thechapter}
{4ex}
{\titlerule
\vspace{2ex}%
\filright}
[\vspace{2ex}%
\titlerule]

\usepackage[fullvoc]{arabxetex}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}


\begin{document}
\chapter{My Chapter}

Test

\end{document}
```

Comment: may be `\usepackage[fullvoc]{arabxetex}` should be loaded before titleformating... Not tested, but it seems possible for me that arabxetex could redefine titles

Comment: @koleygr Change of order gives this error message: `Package bidi Error: Oops! you have loaded package titlesec after bidi package. Please load package titlesec before bidi package, and then try to run xelatex on your document again.`

Comment: Ok... try to place  `\usepackage[fullvoc]{arabxetex}` just after `\usepackage{titlesec}` and give the rest of the commands under that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my tested answer (but without arabic text):

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}


\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[fullvoc]{arabxetex}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Linux Libertine O}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\bfseries\Large}
{\filleft\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} \Huge\thechapter}
{4ex}
{\titlerule
\vspace{2ex}%
\filright}
[\vspace{2ex}%
\titlerule]

\begin{document}
\chapter{My Chapter}

Test

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This ordering works. I hope someone would explain the reason.

Comment: @blackened As I said in my first comment, arabxetex redefines chapter styles. If you make your changes to chapter using `\titleformat` command before loading `arabxetex`, the last (`arabxetex`) will redefine the chapter to its default. So, you have to give the `\titleformat` command after loading `arabxetex`

Comment: You just missed my word `titleformating` from this first comment that was refering to the `\titleformat` command and not to the `titlesec` package